# Role table gone, Rails Devise on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

am new to rails & this is my first app .. I used devise & CanCan for authentication & authorization & there was a predefined set of roles for every user that I can assign it to ... Working perfectly on my local machine .. once deployed to Heroku & migrated the database everything seemed in place but when I tried to assign a role to a user there was none .

Any idea what's wrong?

I also wanted to disable the sign-up & only allow admins to create users

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

After too much searching I found out that the missing part is the Role table from the rolify gem, for some reason it refuses to migrate on the PostgreSQL/Heroku.

& the issue is raised in this link, still didn't find a solution that worked for me 
https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/76

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run all the migrations on Heroku. Do this: `heroku run rake db:migrate` and try again.

Comment: Tried that but no luck, I bet there's a conflict between Devise & Heroku but I have no idea about where to look for it !!

Comment: Have you done a `git add .` ? After that do a `git status` to see if you have missed out anything.

Comment: Done that as well, everything is up to date but still nothing,
I've found something on the wiki for this gem that's talking about troubleshooting Heroku

Using devise on Heroku with Ruby on Rails 3.1 requires setting:

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
Read more about the potential issues at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: It's heroku restart I guess .. & it's not doing anything as well.